# linux copy command no destination

Tags: linux

I want to just copy some files and paste them somewhere else in another command. The reason is my source and my destination are on two different servers and I need to switch to a new server before pasting the files. Which linux command can I use to do so?

Comment: Conceptually that question makes no sense. A copy must have a destination by definition even if it was `/dev/null`.

Comment: I never said I have no destination. i have indicated in the question that my destination is on another server :) If you are talking about the title, it is because cp requires a destination, but I couldnt put anything there since it was on another server

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept here "copy some files and paste them"... uhh... this sounds like Windows all over. Some basic guide to Unix/Linux/Commandline is recommended, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you really need is `scp`

example of use: `scp local_file user@remote:~/path/to/place/remotely`

[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be ask those two servers to communicate directly, a concept once called *remote ftp*. The command `rcp` (remote copy) can also handle copying from two non-local systems, but AFAIK, the traffic goes through the machine executing rcp.